# Changing Select Effect of a row in leanback

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

> The RowPresenter draws a dim overlay on top of the row view for views
>   that are not selected.

I changed the style of my cards in some rows.

Now I have rows with card `style X` and other with the default card style of the `ImageCardView`.

How to know the `card presenter` of the previous row ? I want to apply a custom effect, since the default effect is not compatible with `style X` (with transparent background)

```
public class CustomListRowPresenter extends ListRowPresenter {

    @Override
    protected void onSelectLevelChanged(RowPresenter.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onSelectLevelChanged(holder);

        //if the previous selected row have the style X then apply a custom effect 
        //else apply the default one
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to check this [tutorial](http://corochann.com/browsefragment-listrow-customization-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-18-705.html) which shows sample shadow customization by modifying `Presenter` class. This also shows how to use `CustomListRow` and `CustomListRowPresenter` in MainFragment or to set `Presenter`, you can specify it in the constructor of rows adapter. Hope it will help.

Comment: There is no example how to make a custom effect, they just mention that we can disable the effect, the default effect is applied on the hole row , in my case i want to make the effect only on each imageview in the row , in this way if i have a round image , the effect wont be on the card (only on the round image)